# Why does reading the standard output cause my process to exit?

Tags: .net, process, f#

I am trying to read the list of branches from a Git repo from .NET.

This script works:

```ml
open System.Diagnostics

[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module Async =

  let parallel2 a b =
    async {
      let! x = Async.StartChild a
      let! y = Async.StartChild b

      let! i = x
      let! j = y

      return i, j
    }

async {
  let fileName = "git"
  let args = [ "-P"; "branch"; "-a" ]

  let psi = ProcessStartInfo(
    FileName = fileName,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true
  )

  for arg in args do
    psi.ArgumentList.Add(arg)

  let p = Process.Start(psi, EnableRaisingEvents = true)

  let! ct = Async.CancellationToken

  let! output, () =
    Async.parallel2
      (
        p.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync()
        |> Async.AwaitTask
      )
      (
        p.WaitForExitAsync(ct)
        |> Async.AwaitTask
      )

  if p.ExitCode <> 0 then
    let! error =
      p.StandardError.ReadToEndAsync()
      |> Async.AwaitTask

    return failwith $"{error}"
  else
    return output
}
|> Async.RunSynchronously
|> printfn "%s"
```

However, this script will never terminate:

```ml
open System.Diagnostics

async {
  let fileName = "git"
  let args = [ "-P"; "branch"; "-a" ]

  let psi = ProcessStartInfo(
    FileName = fileName,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true
  )

  for arg in args do
    psi.ArgumentList.Add(arg)

  let p = Process.Start(psi, EnableRaisingEvents = true)

  let! ct = Async.CancellationToken

  do!
    p.WaitForExitAsync(ct)
    |> Async.AwaitTask

  if p.ExitCode <> 0 then
    let! error =
      p.StandardError.ReadToEndAsync()
      |> Async.AwaitTask

    return failwith $"{error}"
  else
    let! output =
      p.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync()
      |> Async.AwaitTask

    return output
}
|> Async.RunSynchronously
|> printfn "%s"
```

Why is this?

---

Some notes:

- It gets stuck at `WaitForExitAsync`
- I am using .NET 6 on Ubuntu

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on where during the execution does it gets stuck? I tested this (in FSI 12.0.5.0 for F# 6.0 on Windows) and it worked fine and returned the list of branches..

Comment: Stuck on `WaitForExitAsync`. This may be a .NET on Linux issue?

Comment: I ran the code as a console program targeting .NET 6 on Fedora and it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it gets stuck at WaitForExitAsync is that the child process can wait for the standard output and standard error buffers to be clear before exiting. For this reason the parent process has to read the buffers to completion before waiting for exit. However the same problem can happen if you try to wait for the standard error buffer to end while the process is writing to standard output or vice-versa.

So the only way to do it is to begin asyncronous reads from both standard error and standard output, wait for them to clear, then wait for the program to exit:

```
let read_error  = p.StandardError.ReadToEndAsync()
let read_output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync()

do! p.WaitForExitAsync(ct) |> Async.AwaitTask

let! output = read_output |> Async.AwaitTask
let! error =  read_error  |> Async.AwaitTask

if p.ExitCode <> 0 then return failwith $"{error}"
else return output
```

More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?view=net-7.0#remarks